# Get the predictions using DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM after fine-tuning Llama2 using SFT trainer

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

I am in the process of fine-tuning Llama2 using SFT trainer and quantization using Lora.
my dataset is composed of questions structured like:

```
<s>[INST] 
<<SYS>> Please select the correct answer from the given multiple Options based on the given Context: <</SYS>>  
 Context: Abrasion is another type of mechanical weathering. With abrasion, one rock bumps against another rock. Gravity causes abrasion as a rock tumbles down a slope. Moving water causes abrasion it moves rocks so that they bump against one another (Figure 9.3). Strong winds cause abrasion by blasting sand against rock surfaces.  
 Question: Gravity causes erosion by all of the following except  \
 Options:(A) glaciers (B) moving air (C) flowing water (D) mass movement  
 Answer: [/INST] D </s>
```

And I am currently using DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM to compute the loss based on the predicted answers.
In my case this is the instruction structure:

Do I provide the context, question and options as an instruction_template?

```
instruction_template = "</SYS>>\n\n Context:" response_template = "Answer: [/INST]" collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(instruction_template=instruction_template, response_template=response_template, tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)
```

OR

```
response_template = "Answer: [/INST]" collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(response_template=response_template, tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)
```

I have tried multiple response templates but always get the error:
RuntimeError: Could not find response key [835, 4007, 22137, 29901] in token IDs tensor([ 1, 835, ...])

Can you please guide me to the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most other tokenizers, llama-2 tokenizer depends on the context. For example-

```
sent-1: """### User: Hello\n\n### Assistant: Hi, how can I help you?"""
sent-2: "### Assistant:"
```

Here token-id for `### Assistant:` will be different as sent-1 has `\n` as context while sent-2 doesn't.

**Solution:** Tokenizing with same context is the end solution.
[Here](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/sft_trainer#using-tokenids-directly-for-responsetemplate) Huggigface is explaining the similar issue in detail.